# What is $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^{1.5}+\theta x}dx=?$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits, definite-integrals, gamma-distribution

Is there a way to obtain an expression for $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^{1.5}+\theta x}dx=?$$

If $\theta=0$, we know the above is the same as $\frac{\Gamma(2/1.5)}{\Gamma(1/1.5)}$ from a generalized Gamma function. Also, I am interested in $$\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x^{1.5}+\theta x}dx=?$$ or, $$\int_0^{\infty}\sqrt xe^{-x^{1.5}+\theta x}dx=?$$

It seems the 2nd integral above has to do with the generalized normal density, but coudn't figure out the exact connection. I am particularly interested in the limiting behavior of the above integrals when $\theta$ gets very large?

Any help or intuitions would be very appreciated!

Comment: Note that by the Liebniz integral rule,$$\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x^{1.5}+\theta x}dx = \frac{d}{d \theta} \left[ \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^{1.5}+\theta x}dx \right].$$So if you have a closed-form expression for the first integral, it's easy to find an expression for the second (and maybe even vice versa.)

Comment: Maple is able to generate closed-form expressions for the three integrals in terms of hyper-geometric functions and  modified Bessel  functions.

Comment: For each $a>-1$, the integral $$J_a=\int_0^\infty x^ae^{-x\sqrt x+\theta x}dx$$ is $$J_a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty I^a_n\frac{\theta^n}{n!}$$ where, for every nonnegative $n$, $$I_n^a=\int_0^\infty x^ax^ne^{-x\sqrt{x}}dx=\frac23\int_0^\infty t^{2(n+a)/3}e^{-t}t^{-1/3}dt=\frac23\int_0^\infty t^{2(n+a+1)/3-1}e^{-t}dt$$ hence $$I_n^a=\frac23\Gamma\left(\frac23(n+a+1)\right)$$ and $$J_a=\frac23\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Gamma\left(\frac23(n+a+1)\right)\frac{\theta^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this integral can be approximated for large $\theta$ using a variant of saddle-point integration.  I should preface this by noting that it's been a long time since I've had to do an integral this way, so I'll be (roughly) following the technique in [these notes.](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2011f/saddle.pdf)  I welcome any corrections to/complaints about the derivation below.

Change variables such that 
$$
w = \sqrt{2 \theta}\left(\sqrt{x} - \frac{2\theta}{3}\right).
$$
The integral as a function of $\theta$ is then
\begin{align}
I(\theta) &= \int_0^\infty \exp (-x^{3/2} + \theta x) dx \\ &= \int_{-(2\theta)^{3/2}/3}^\infty  \exp \left[ \frac{4 \theta^3}{27} - \frac{w^2}{2} - \frac{w^3}{(2 \theta)^{3/2}}\right] \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\theta}}\left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{2 \theta}} + \frac{2\theta}{3} \right)dw \\
&= \frac{2 \sqrt{2 \theta}}{3} e^{4 \theta^3/27} \int_{-(2\theta)^{3/2}/3}^\infty  e^{-w^2/2} \left(1 + \frac{3 w}{(2 \theta)^{3/2}} \right) \left[ 1 - \frac{w^3}{(2 \theta)^{3/2}} + \frac{w^6}{2 (2\theta)^3} + \dots \right]  dw
\end{align}
where in the last term we have expanded $e^{-w^3/(2 \theta)^{3/2}}$ about $w = 0$.

Now, the integral will largely be dominated by the Gaussian factor $e^{-w^2/2}$ over the region of integration.  This means** that we can extend the range of integration to the entire real axis, as the relative error introduced this way is small.  Thus, the integral can be approximated as
$$
I(\theta) \approx \frac{2 \sqrt{2 \theta}}{3} e^{4 \theta^3/27} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-w^2/2} \left[1 + \frac{3w - w^3}{2^{3/2}} \theta^{-3/2} + \frac{w^6/2- 3w^4}{8\theta^3} + \mathcal{O}(\theta^{-9/2}) \right]
$$
Since the second term is square brackets is an odd polynomial, it vanishes in the integration.  In fact, the $\mathcal{O}(\theta^{-9/2})$ term in the expansion will be an odd polynomial as well;  the next non-vanishing integral will be $\mathcal{O}(\theta^{-6})$. We are left with the result that
$$
\boxed{I(\theta) \approx  \frac{4 \sqrt{\pi \theta} }{3} e^{4 \theta^3/27} \left( 1 - \frac{3}{16}\theta^{-3} + \mathcal{O}(\theta^{-6})\right).}
$$

---

** NOTE:  This is the part I'm least sure about.  In the standard sort of saddle-point integration, one has the lower bound of integration of the integral approaching $-\infty$ as the square root of some parameter;  here, it's going as the 3/2 power of that parameter.  My intuition is that this actually means that the error introduced by extending the integral to the real line is lower than that in the standard case, but there may be a subtlety I'm missing.

Comment: @JuanOspina:  Thanks for the confirmation that I'm not completely wrong.  I've made one correction to my change of variables, and my result now agrees with the exact result obtained by Mathematica in the limit.  (Mathematica returns a result in terms of Airy functions.)  Your result still differs from mine by a factor of 2/3, though; any idea where the discrepancy might be?

Comment: I am  checking  and now I am completely sure that your result is correct.   My result has a wrong factor of 2/3.  I will check my computation.  All the best.

Answer (score 0):

For the first integral, Maple is giving the following result

[image]

when θ gets  large we obtain

[image]

and for very  large values of θ is reduced to

[image]

Using the approximation

[image]

we obtain the asymptotic result

[image]

The following picture shows the behavior of the integral respect to θ

[image]

Comment: Wow!! You people are amazingly helpful. I will carefully check these comments when I get to work this afternoon. Thanks so much!!